# Is this a bug in Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, delphi-2009

It certainly looks like a bug, but I only have the trial version so it may have been fixed.

```
ITestInterface = interface
  ['{9445CED8-4DBA-4EDB-9897-60980B438BE4}']
  procedure Foo1;
  procedure Foo2;
end;

TTest = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestInterface)

end;
```

The above will rightly not compile. but the following does!

```
ITestInterface<t> = interface
  ['{9445CED8-4DBA-4EDB-9897-60980B438BE4}']
  procedure Foo1;
  procedure Foo2;
end;

TTest<T> = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestInterface<T>)

end;
```

Edit: I have just found it it will fail if you try and instantiate TTest. So a little inconsistent, but not that bad!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, a bug. http://qc.codegear.com/ is the place to go to report bugs.

Comment: Since I only have the trial, I wasn't sure if this has already been fixed in the full release.